# SQL Query to get Top 1 with greatest modifieddate From Group BY ID. How can i achieve this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MergeAndDeleteNonprofitDetails](
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [ToJKNonprofitID] [int] NULL,
    [ToNGOID] [int] NULL,
    [ToOrgName] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [ToOrgEIN] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ToJKStatus] [int] NULL,
    [ToOrganizationID] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ToOrgZipCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ToLastModifiedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [FromJKNonprofitID] [int] NULL,
    [FromNGOID] [int] NULL,
    [FromOrgName] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [FromOrgEIN] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FromJKStatus] [int] NULL,
    [FromOrganizationID] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [FromOrgZipCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FromLastModifiedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsMerged] [bit]
)
```

I need to select the data with Greatest `ToLastModifiedDate` and `FromLastModifiedDate` `GROUP BY ToOrganizationID`. How Can i achieve this?

NOTE: There can be multiple data corresponding to one `ToOrganizationID` with different `FromOrganizationID`. Hence we need to compare between columns and within one row for finding Greatest `ToLastModifiedDate` and `FromLastModifiedDate`.

SAMPLE DATA:

[image: sample data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with C as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over(partition by ToOrganizationID order by ToLastModifiedDate desc) as rnTo,
         row_number() over(partition by ToOrganizationID order by FromLastModifiedDate desc) as rnFrom
  from MergeAndDeleteNonprofitDetails
)
select *
from C
where rnTo = 1 or
      rnFrom = 1
```